# How to show $\sqrt{\text{Tr}(A^2)} \leq \text{Tr}(A)$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, trace

Let $A$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. How to show that Frobenius norm is less than trace of the matrix? Formally,
$$\sqrt{\text{Tr}(A^2)} \leq \text{Tr}(A)$$
Also, show when $A$ is an $n \times m$ the following is true
$$\sqrt{\text{Tr}(A^TA)} \leq \|A\|_*$$
where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is nuclear norm which is the summation of the singular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first you can assume that $A$ is diagonal with diagonal entries
$a_1,\ldots,a_n$, all $\ge0$. Then your inequality becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2$$
which is clearly true on expanding the right side, recalling all variables
are non-negative.

Comment: How about the other?

Comment: How about applying the first to the psd square root of $A^TA$? @Saeed

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_r$ be the singular values of $A$.
Then
$$\sqrt{\text{Tr}(A^\top A)} = \sqrt{\sum_i \sigma^2_r} \le \sum_i |\sigma_r| = \|A\|_*.$$